# Using RxJava to temporarily save variables during configuration changes

Tags: android, rx-java

I am using RxJava on an Android project and want to make sure I'm implementing something correctly.

I am using an Observable to login to a server. After the login occurs I may want to save the username on the client side so I'm using the doOnNext() operator to do this. Here's an example of what this looks like:

```
Observable<Response<Void>> doLogin(Observable<Response<Void>> retainedObservable, Subscriber subscriber, String username, String password, boolean saveUsername)     {
if (retainedObservable == null) {
    retainedObservable = networkLayer.loginWithcredentials(username, password)
    .doOnNext(new Action1<Response<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Response<Void> voidResponse) {
            if (saveUsername) {
                databaseLayer.saveUsername(username).subscribe();
            } else {
                databaseLayer.saveUsername(null).subscribe();
            }
        }
    })
    .cache();
}

    mSubscription = retainedObservable.subscribeOn().observeOn().subscribe(subscriber);
    return retainedObservable;
}
```

If the device goes through a configuration change before the login finishes I want to be able to resubscribe to the observable that was running so that I don't have to ask the user to reenter their credentials of press the login button again.

To accomplish this I initially call doLogin(...) and temporarily save the returned observable in a data holder class. If the device goes through a configuration change I can grab the already created observable from the data holder class and resubscribe to it. This works great, my only hang up is that I need to also temporarily save off the username, password and saveUsername flag. This is easy enough to do, however I'm wondering if there's a way I can leverage RxJava to hold these values in the Observable and still have access to them when I need them in doOnNext(...). If I don't do this and just resubscribe to the Observable then when doOnNext(...) runs I won't have values for the saveUsername flag or the username which is obviously bad.

It would be really nice to only have to retain the Observable and somehow have it retain the username, password and saveUsername flag. Is there a way to accomplish this in RxJava or is the way I'm currently doing it the way it needs to be done if I want those variables to be retained during a configuration change?

Comment: Is retainedObservable and cachedObservable supposed to be the same? Currently retainedObservable doesn't actually appear to be used for anything

Comment: Good catch. I made a mistake transferring it. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yes. RxJava uses a functional, stateless API, so you're not really able (or supposed) to attach additional data to an observable aside from the values it returns.

As with functional languages, there are generally two ways you can go about this:

- You can either capture additional values in a closure, similar to how
  you are doing it now. But obviously those values will only be
  accessible within the scope of said closure, so you can't return an
  Observable from a method and still access variables that were used to
  create it later.
- If you do need to access that data at a later point, the usual approach is to create some kind of result object that contains all your data. For example a "LoginResult" class, that contains your response as well as the original login data.